# Array elements in String PHP: How can I print_r the matching elements in the order of the string?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to identify several `Array` elements present in a string. I'd like to print_r the matching elements as an array in the order of the string.

Example and trial **:**

```
$string = "hello my dear, how are you doing today ?";
$array = array('are', 'today','hello','bonjour','Holà', 'Wassup');
$result = array('hello','are','today');

function match($array , $string ){
   foreach ($array as $a) {
      if (strpos($string ,$a) == true) {
         return $a;
      }
   }
}
```

The function returns the following error :

> strpos(): needle is not a string or an integer

Any idea ??

Thanks a lot from France !

Comment: `var_dump($a)` gives what?

Comment: strpos returns integer(position) and not true if found and false if not found

Comment: study https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strpos.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you `return` as soon as you find one match, rather than building an array of all the matching strings. In terms of returning the strings in the order they occur in the string, you can use the return value from `strpos` as an array key, and then `ksort` the result array before returning it:

```
$string = "hello my dear, how are you doing today ?";
$array = array('are', 'today','hello','bonjour','Holà', 'Wassup');

function match($array , $string ) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if (($pos = strpos($string, $a)) !== false) {
            $result[$pos] = $a;
        }
    }
    ksort($result);
    return array_values($result);
}

print_r(match($array, $string));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => are
    [2] => today
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/iacDu)

Note that there is an issue with using `strpos` in that it doesn't consider whether a match is a complete word or not. So for example, `match(['are'], 'hare')` will return `['are']`. You can work around this by using [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match) in place of `strpos`, and surrounding your search string with `\b` (a word boundary):

```
function match($array , $string ) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if (preg_match("~\b$a\b~", $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
            $result[$matches[0][1]] = $a;
        }
    }
    ksort($result);
    return array_values($result);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
print_r(match($array, $string));
print_r(match(['are'], 'hare'));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => are
    [2] => today
)
Array
(
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fnGcD)

You can further simplify that by using [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and combining all the elements of `$array` into a regex alternation:

```
function match($array , $string ) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if (preg_match_all('~\b' . implode('\b|\b', $array) . '\b~', $string, $matches)) {
            $result = $matches[0];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PJGVQ)

Comment: preg_match_all could be applied here as well. in general preg_match is going to be more useful than strpos but, they are different animals so its what you are comfortable with

Comment: @ChrisRichardson absolutely - I was trying to keep the answer as close to OP's code as possible. I will make a note about the issue in regards to word boundaries though.

Comment: @Nick it works very good ! Actually, the first option matches perfectly what i wanted to achieve. Thanks for the other options ! They will definitely help in the near future !!

Answer (score 0):

I can advice next approach:

1. explode string to array of words
2. compare 2 arrays in loop"

   ```
   <?php
   $string = "hello my dear, how are you doing today ?";
   $array = array('are', 'today','hello','bonjour','Holà', 'Wassup');

   function match($array , $string ) {
       $result = [];
       $string_to_arr = explode(' ', $string);
       foreach ($string_to_arr as $s) {
         if (in_array($s, $array)) {
            array_push($result, $s);
         }
       }

       return $result;
   }

   print_r(match($array , $string ));
   ```

[You can try live PHP code on PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=4a39cede20295533ca6fbb8c748c4531&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Answer (score 0):

You can split your original string into a word array, and then intersect that with your word list.

```
<?php
$string = "hello my dear, how are you doing today ?";
$array  = array('are', 'today','hello','bonjour','Holà', 'Wassup');
$result = array('hello','are','today');

$matched = 
    array_values(
        array_intersect(
            str_word_count($string, 1),
            $array
        )
    );

var_dump($result === $matched);
var_export($matched);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
array (
  0 => 'hello',
  1 => 'are',
  2 => 'today',
)
```

You could swap the `str_word_count($string, 1)` for `preg_split('/\b/', $string)`.

However the above is case sensitive.

You could swap out `array_intersect` for `array_uintersect` with a case compare.

```
array_uintersect(str_word_count($string, 1), $array, 'strcasecmp')
```

For multibyte case comparisons you are probably better off with the `preg_match` route with the appropriate flags or another comparison function.

Answer (score -1):

my original answer was bunk just remove the == true

Comment: this is correct. just because I am not being educational isnt the problem the if statment switches on the result of the function any non-zero result will pass into the return function

Comment: What about case when one array word appears more when once in string? Another case array entry word is sub-word in string?